# subquery in spring jpa repository

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I want to translate the Sql query to spring jpa repository

select * from TableName1 where CLIENT_ID = (select id from tableName2 where tableName2.columnName
LIKE 'criteria');

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in Spring data JPA using JPQL. JPQL supports [EXISTS with subqueries](http://openjpa.apache.org/builds/1.2.0/apache-openjpa-1.2.0/docs/manual/jpa_langref.html#jpa_langref_exists) . Nest subqueries in JPA are called correlated sub-queries and one can always re-write them using EXISTS as shown below

```
SELECT t1 FROM TableName1 t1 WHERE EXISTS 
           ( SELECT t2 FROM tableName2 t2 
             WHERE t1.client_id = t2.id AND t2.column_name LIKE '%criteria%'
           )
```